# NSTableView not updating on OSX 10.9

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview

I have written a small application, initially under OSX 10.8, that receives MIDI events via MidiEventCallback and puts the data into a NSMutableArray that is a member of a NSTableViewDataSource.

In [this video](http://youtu.be/kdquZEmx2Vg) you can see how it worked without any problems on OSX 10.8.

Now I have a new MacBook that runs on OSX 10.9, installed XCode and got all my project files and compiled the application.

Have connected my MIDI controller to my MacBook, started the application and pressing keys on the MIDI controller.

The problem:

- The NSTableView is not being updated as it should. If I press my piano keys, no MIDI messages will be displayed and after a couple of seconds I get an exception. Here is a screenshot of what XCode is showing me then:

[image: Exception when playing my MIDI piano without resizing the window of my application.]

- I stop the application and start it again. Now, when pressing keys, I resize the application window continuously and the NSTableView does update properly, no exception, everything fine.
- Same when I press some piano keys a couple of times. Then bring some other application to the front and then my application to the front again. Again, all MIDI messages are displayed properly in my NSTableView.

Any idea what this can be? Is it a OSX 10.9 related issue or could it be with changing to a new MacBook. Am running out of options.

What I have tried is connecting the NSWindow of my application as an IBOutlet to my controller that acts as a NSTableViewDataSource and tried the following calls right after I did *[tableView reloadData]*

- *[window update]*
- *[window display]*
- *[window flushWindow]*

but nothing helped. Any help highly appreciated.

**EDIT**

Did some more debugging following the comments and actually was looking at the wrong place.

Here some code for more context:

My controller has a property called *MidiEventListener* that receives all MIDI events and puts them into *eventList*.

```
@interface MidiAidController()
  ...
  @property NSMutableArray *eventList;
  @property MidiEventListener* listener;
@end
```

In the *init* method of my controller I do the following

```
_eventList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
MidiEventCallback eventCallback = ^(MidiEvent* midiEvent)
{
  [[self eventList] addObject:midiEvent];
  [[self tableView] reloadData];
};
...
self.listener = [[MidiEventListener alloc] initWithCallback:eventCallback];
```

In *MidiEventListener*, within *initWithCallback*, the following happens:

```
result = MIDIInputPortCreate(_midiClient, CFSTR("Input"), midiInputCallback, (__bridge_retained void *)(self), &_inputPort);
```

Now, let's go over to *midiInputCallback*:

```
static void midiInputCallback(const MIDIPacketList* list, void *procRef, void *srcRef)
{
  MidiEventListener *midiEventListener = (__bridge MidiEventListener*)procRef;
  @autoreleasepool {
    const MIDIPacket *packet = &list->packet[0];

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < list->numPackets; i++)
    {
        MidiEvent* midiEvent = [[MidiEvent alloc] initWithPacket:packet];
        midiEventListener.midiEventCallback(midiEvent);
        packet = MIDIPacketNext(packet);
    }
  }
}
```

That is basically it. The Exception happens at *midiEventListener.midiEventCallback(midiEvent);*. I always looked at *[tableView reloadData] since that was the line when clicking under *Thread 6 - 19__25...* (see screenshot above). But when I click on *Thread 6 - 20 midiInputCallback* then I get this line highlighted.

**SOLUTION**

Reloading the data has to be done from the main thread:

```
MidiEventCallback eventCallback = ^(MidiEvent* midiEvent)
{
  [[self eventList] addObject:midiEvent];
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){[[self tableView] reloadData];});
};
```

Comment: What kind of exception are you getting?  Have you set an Xcode breakpoint in your callback method to see if touching the MIDI keyboard is firing in there? (in other words, let's see if we can figure out where the problem *begins*)

Comment: That's the thing. Don't know really where to set a breakpoint. Have added a screenshot above and when I click on the exception trace where it says "19__25 ..." the exception was raised when I did *[[self tableView] reloadData]. It's the CFRetain that makes me curious ...

Comment: You could try setting an xcode breakpoint in your "`MidiEventCallback`" function and see if it hits when you touch the MIDI device keyboard.

Comment: Did some more debugging and was actually looking at the wrong place and too much focused on *reloadData*. edited my question above and provided some more context with code examples. Data comes into the callback and that is where the exception happens. No idea why this happens now on OSX 10.9 and not on OSX 10.8 though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > *Thread 6 - 19__25...* and reloadData

call reload only on Main Thread

e.g.

```
void MyCallback(...) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: From which class would I call it? From AppDelegate, will that be from the main thread then? Any pointers to some good documentation. Flicking through Apples pages on app design to get a better understanding, but am kinda overwhelmed. As of my current understanding, I should put all the code that I currently have in my controllers *init* method into *AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching* and also call *reloadData* from the *AppDelegate*. Is that the right way to go?

Comment: no. just make sure you are on the main thread when coming from the callback. you can dispatch_async a block theere

Comment: Yay, that worked! Thanks a lot! Pushed the updated to Apple and the app is waiting for review :-)

Comment: One question remains: Was that now an OSX 10.9 specific problem of mine? Asked the other way round: Why did this problem never appear on an older and slower MacBook with OSX 10.8, but only on the new one with OSX 10.9?

Comment: dont knwow.. it was never defined and safe and you should always have avoided it